# Optimizing Iteration over dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've dataframe that looks like this:

```
            timestamp    battery_state  battery_level
0   2017-10-08 13:42:02  Charging       0.94
1   2017-10-08 13:45:43  Charging       0.95
2   2017-10-08 13:49:08  Charging       0.96
3   2017-10-08 13:54:07  Charging       0.97
4   2017-10-08 13:57:26  Charging       0.98
5   2017-10-08 14:01:35  Charging       0.99
6   2017-10-08 14:03:03  Full           1.00
7   2017-10-08 14:17:19  Charging       0.98
8   2017-10-08 14:26:05  Charging       0.97
9   2017-10-08 14:46:10  Charging       0.98
10  2017-10-08 14:47:47  Full           1.00
11  2017-10-08 16:36:24  Charging       0.91
12  2017-10-08 16:40:32  Charging       0.92
13  2017-10-08 16:47:58  Charging       0.93
14  2017-10-08 16:51:51  Charging       0.94
15  2017-10-08 16:55:26  Charging       0.95
```

As you guys see in this dataframe i've 3 subsets of samples that corresponde to a device charge period:

- Sample 0 to 6
- Sample 7 to 10
- Sample 11 to 15

**Note:** The charge period isn't always to full state like from Sample 11 to 15

The goal is to get this 3 periods into a variable and processing them when they are founded.

In order to do so i've made this code:

```
previous_index = 0 #stores the initial index of each period

for index in islice(device_charge_samples.index, 1, None): #use islice because the first row does not have privious sample to compare

    #creates a period by comparing each line two by two
    if device_charge_samples.get_value(index, 'battery_level') < device_charge_samples.get_value(index - 1, 'battery_level'):
         subset = device_charge_samples[previous_index:index].reset_index(drop=True)

         #Process subset function here

         previous_index = index

    #last period case
    if index == len(device_charge_samples) - 1:
         subset = device_charge_samples[previous_index:index + 1].reset_index(drop=True)

         #Process subset function here
```

I already replace **device_charge_samples.iteraterows()** for **device_charge_samples.index** on the for cycle and i replace **device_charge_samples.loc[index, 'battery_level]** for **device_charge_samples.get_value(index, 'battery_level')**, both helped a lot.

Is there any other optimization that i can do? , like using the dataframe apply function (which seems to work as a for cycle for each row but i don't know how to use it in this situation, or if is even worth using her), or any other optimization that i can use in my solution

Comment: Please post your desired output, as it's not extremely clear from your description

Comment: The real output is to compute charge rate per hour of each period, but my goal here is only to store each period, one at the time, on the variable 'subset' (each period ('subset') is a dataframe obtained by subseting the original one: 'device_charge_samples[previous_index:index]'). Know i've achived this by doing this loop but is there any other way to do it or optimize it

Answer (score 2):

First create a column which uniquely segments your dataframe using `cumsum`

```
df['group'] = (df.battery_state == 'Full').cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Now you can iterate over the groups instead of iterating over the rows

```
for index, frame in df.groupby('group'):
    subsetFunction(frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.split()` where `battery_state == 'Full'` and drop those rows.

```
m = df['battery_state'] == 'Full'
for subset in np.split(df[~m],df.index[m] - np.arange(sum(m))):
    #1000 loops, best of 3: 783 µs per loop
    # do something with subset here
```

Or as DJK put it with a cumsum (but here a more compact version for fair timing)

```
m  = df.battery_state == 'Full'
for idx, subset in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()):
    # 1000 loops, best of 3: 999 µs per loop
    # do something with subset here
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
timestamp            battery_state  battery_level
2017-10-08T13:42:02  Charging       0.94
2017-10-08T13:45:43  Charging       0.95
2017-10-08T13:49:08  Charging       0.96
2017-10-08T13:54:07  Charging       0.97
2017-10-08T13:57:26  Charging       0.98
2017-10-08T14:01:35  Charging       0.99
2017-10-08T14:03:03  Full           1.00
2017-10-08T14:17:19  Charging       0.98
2017-10-08T14:26:05  Charging       0.97
2017-10-08T14:46:10  Charging       0.98
2017-10-08T14:47:47  Full           1.00
2017-10-08T16:36:24  Charging       0.91
2017-10-08T16:40:32  Charging       0.92
2017-10-08T16:47:58  Charging       0.93
2017-10-08T16:51:51  Charging       0.94
2017-10-08T16:55:26  Charging       0.95'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', parse_dates=['timestamp'])

m = df['battery_state'] == 'Full'
for subset in np.split(df[~m],df.index[m] - np.arange(sum(m))):
    print(subset)
```

Returns:

```
            timestamp battery_state  battery_level
0 2017-10-08 13:42:02      Charging           0.94
1 2017-10-08 13:45:43      Charging           0.95
2 2017-10-08 13:49:08      Charging           0.96
3 2017-10-08 13:54:07      Charging           0.97
4 2017-10-08 13:57:26      Charging           0.98
5 2017-10-08 14:01:35      Charging           0.99
            timestamp battery_state  battery_level
7 2017-10-08 14:17:19      Charging           0.98
8 2017-10-08 14:26:05      Charging           0.97
9 2017-10-08 14:46:10      Charging           0.98
             timestamp battery_state  battery_level
11 2017-10-08 16:36:24      Charging           0.91
12 2017-10-08 16:40:32      Charging           0.92
13 2017-10-08 16:47:58      Charging           0.93
14 2017-10-08 16:51:51      Charging           0.94
15 2017-10-08 16:55:26      Charging           0.95
```